# Adding a textView or an Expandable textView programmatically through looping

Tags: android, json, loops, textview

I had to work with a `JSON` output that basically would show me the number of questions asked along with the reply that I am getting. 
The following `JSON` output sums up what I am trying to say:

```
{ "data" : [ { "answer" : "You have better opportunities if you go abroad. If you are interested in IT, then go for it. You will do better in IT.",
        "category_id" : "1",
        "category_name" : "Education",
        "created_on" : "25 Apr, 2013 11:45",
        "is_answered" : true,
        "modified_on" : "26 Apr, 2013 07:20",
        "parent_id" : "0",
        "question" : "I am thinking of continuing my further studies. Is it a good for me to apply aborad or study here?",
        "question_id" : "2",
        "user_id" : "17"
      },
      { "answer" : "According to your chart, you are facing the malefic affect of the planet Saturn. You can reduce this malefic affect by offering water to Peepal tree on Saturdays. ",
        "category_id" : "3",
        "category_name" : "Health",
        "created_on" : "25 Apr, 2013 20:21",
        "is_answered" : true,
        "modified_on" : "26 Apr, 2013 11:49",
        "parent_id" : "0",
        "question" : "I am having a trouble in my business. What should i do?",
        "question_id" : "3",
        "user_id" : "17"
      },
      { "answer" : "Your question has been posted to blamethestars.com. We wil get back to you soon.",
        "category_id" : "2",
        "category_name" : "Career",
        "created_on" : "26 Apr, 2013 11:21",
        "is_answered" : false,
        "modified_on" : "",
        "parent_id" : "0",
        "question" : "what is the best field of work for me?",
        "question_id" : "4",
        "user_id" : "17"
      }
    ],
  "message" : null,
  "status" : "success"
}
```

So what I had to do was show this in a very presentable way, and what I did was used HTML type formatting to display the result, where I presented the question in a **bold** typeface, and then I presented the answer in a *italic* typeface. The code is as follows:

```
    try{

        jArray = jObj.getJSONArray("data");
        for(int i = 0; i<jArray.length();i++)
        {
            jObj2 = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            if(result_JSON.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                result_JSON = "<b><font color =\"#6C2C6B\">"+jObj2.getString("question")+"</font></b><br/>";
            else
                result_JSON = result_JSON+"<b><font color =\"#6C2C6B\">"+jObj2.getString("question")+"</font></b><br/>";
            if(jObj2.getString("answer").equalsIgnoreCase("null"))
                result_JSON = result_JSON+"<i>We will get back to you soon</i><br/>";
            else
                result_JSON = result_JSON+"<i>"+jObj2.getString("answer")+"</i><br/>";
            Log.i("QUESTION", result_JSON);
        }


        question_answer_view.setText(Html.fromHtml(result_JSON));
         if(question_answer_view.getText().toString().length()<1)
         {
             question_answer_view.setText("NO Q & A TO DISPLAY");
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No questions asked till now.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
```

where `question_answer_view` is a textView.

and the xml file for this is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#eeeeee" >


    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

      <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

          <TextView
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Question and Answers"
              android:textSize="20sp"
              android:textAllCaps="true"
              android:textColor="#6C2C6B"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>


      </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
              android:id="@+id/question_answer_stack"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textSize="15sp"
              android:background="#ffffff"
              android:textColor="#000000"/>

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

So what I would like to do now is to arrange for each question and answer thread, a separate textView, and because the question and answer thread is unique to each user of the application, setting it up in the xml file would not make much sense. Ultimately I thought I would want to generate the textView programmatically, but I have no idea being very new to android, someone please help. And the other question is how do I access different features on textView this way like the `android:background` or `android:layout_width` etc.
If there is another approach to this problem, I am very open to that too.

P.S. I do apologize, the question is very long, but please do help.

Answer (score 1):

You want a `ListView` or a `GridView`, and populate that with your `CustomItem` views. You will also need a `CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter` to fill the said list with your items.

`CustomItem` view should be defined in XML as a view. Then, in the `CustomAdapter` you inflate those views as many times as you need. The ListView will only request teh number of Views and Views themselves, to it works out-of-box with all sorts of custom data, as long as they have adapters/XML to back them up.

Consider this approach, give it a shot, report back. Do try to avoid "programatically adding GUI" like you would in Swing, AWT or QT - it's rather painful.

I have a few examples of this approach in my answers as well.

Comment: wow I didnt think about that ... thank you for the suggestion, I will reply really soon though using this approach, not now but soon enough. I actually have some other work to do now ... sorry about that.

Comment: It's cool. I'll probably be in the office tomorrow as well ;) glad to help.